# SwiftData bind @Query variable

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-data

currently doing a flow layout list with a drag behaviour to change order. So I have

```swift
@Query var categories: [Category]
```

```swift
ForEach(categories) { category in
    Text(category.name)
    .onDrag({
        withAnimation {
            self.draggedCategory = category
            return NSItemProvider(object: String(category.name) as NSString)
        }
    })
    .onDrop(of: [.text],
        delegate: MyDropDelegate(
        item: category,
        items: $categories,
        draggedItem: $draggedCategory
    ))
}
```

```swift
struct MyDropDelegate : DropDelegate {
    let item : Category
    @Binding var items : [Category]
    @Binding var draggedItem : Category?

    func performDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func dropEntered(info: DropInfo) {
        guard let draggedItem = self.draggedItem else {
            return
        }

        if draggedItem != item {
            let from = items.firstIndex(of: draggedItem)!
            let to = items.firstIndex(of: item)!
            withAnimation(.default) {
                self.items.move(fromOffsets: IndexSet(integer: from), toOffset: to > from ? to + 1 : to)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I have this error : Cannot find '$categories' in scope on this line : "items: $categories,"

Anyone have a solution ?

I tried some Bindable(items) but nothing worked

Comment: Binding to a Query is a fallacy. A Query is for read-only. The only way to affect it is inserting and updating the context. Binding is by definition a two-way connection.

Comment: And it’s not the array itself that is persisted but the objects it holds so those are what you need to update. Basically you need to do three things here, 1) add a property to Category that holds the order 2) update this property for the dragged object and all others affected by the drag in `dropEntered(info:)` 3) add sorting on this property to your query